# Vertically aligning 90 degree rotated text

Tags: html, css, rotation

What I want to do is, to vertically align collapsed blocks on give website:

http://maliyyemenecment.com/?language=en

I tried all possible ways, to align words with bottom side. I mean, constant margin from bottom side. The problem is, can't achieve any good result. Any suggestions?

[image]

Thx in advance

Comment: ***Visually*** it looks like it's the `bottom`, but it's actually the elements `left` side.

Comment: Add text-align:left to .kwicks.horizontal li .block .collapsed .more span  and margin-right: -100px;

Answer (score 3):

`.kwicks.horizontal li .block .collapsed` has a `text-align:right;` replace it with `text-align: left;` (as the "bottom" is actually the left side of the element) and set a `text-indent` (works for me when making this edit in developer tools)

```
.kwicks.horizontal li .block .collapsed {
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 17px;
}
```

Comment: Please take a look. http://maliyyemenecment.com/?language=az  Why http://screencast.com/t/7hEQAE0vOb this block appears as 2 lines?

Comment: To fix that, you need to remove the `float: right` from `.kwicks.horizontal li .block .collapsed .more span` and to increase its width from 100px to, let's say 200px.